# Android debugger navigating me to the error response after properly implemented all the functionalities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I am building an android dictionary app to show the meaning of the word that I will search. I have used Merriam-Webster dictionary API using Volley library and also declared the permission in the Manifest file. But whenever I'm debugging the application, It was showing an error response:

```
"coml.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted"
```

Please help me to solve this issue below, I'm providing the snaps from my codes:

[Manifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYGtN.png)

[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUqiz.png)

Comment: Can you check if internet connection is available while running your application on emulator or real device?

Comment: It is there both in System and in the AVD. Cross checked

Comment: Try reinstalling the application, sometimes this issue occurs.

Comment: Have done several times. No changes.